# how to show images from a ArrayList<Bitmap> (SQLlte)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-bitmap

I have this problem where i can not show images (bitmap) from my database in a list on my android studio application.

I can make a picture and save it (base64) in my database and retrieve it. 
But i cannot figure out how to show al the images on a display.

I tried to do it with a list adaptor but that doesnt work :/

```
 ArrayList<Bitmap> listData = new ArrayList<>();

        while(data.moveToNext()){
            //get the value from the database in column 1
            //then add it to the ArrayList

            byte [] encodeByte =Base64.decode(data.getString(1),Base64.DEFAULT);
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            listData.add(bitmap);
        }
```

Comment: Do you have imageView ?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes only one, but i want to have multiple pictures shown (depending on how many pictures are taken by the user)

Comment: then you should not have only one imageView, right ?

Comment: @JohnJoe I just cant figure out how to make multiple views depending on how many pictures. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: @Rachelle yes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the shortcut way to show multiple view depending on the size of  `listData`.

First add `LinearLayout` in `your_current_activity.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</LinearLayout>
```

In java class

```
   LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
   ArrayList<Bitmap> listData = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Bitmap a : listData) {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80, 60));
        image.setMaxHeight(20);
        image.setMaxWidth(20);
        image.setImageBitmap(a);
        linearLayout.addView(image);
      }
```

Below is my output (Assume I have 5 images in listData)

[image]

Comment: YOU are a HERO, im really new to this. Can you give me some advice on how to make te pictures apear underneath each other in stead of next of eachother

Comment: You mean display vertically ?

Comment: yeah, i already changed the size of the pictures and did some margins

Comment: Change `android:orientation="horizontal"` to `android:orientation="vertical"` if you want image displayed vertically.

Comment: OH really that was the first thing i tried, but then al the pictures disapeared

Comment: What have you changed ?

Comment: oh it was prob because of the margins i used, its working THANKS A LOT